# Travelling Salesman with Google Maps API or any other

Tags: google-maps, traveling-salesman

I have a list of addresses and need to find the best route that reaches every address and goes back to the start
With Google Maps API it is possible to calculate this with 8 waypoints I think but 8 isn't enough for my purposes.

Is there someone out there who offers route optimization with more than 8 waypoints? I mean there must be, right? This is a problem that many organisations need a solution to.
It is no problem at all if it costs a lot of money, the calculations are very heavy so I wouldn't expect any free service.
Does maybe google have a paid service for that (for SMEs)?

I'll take any ideas on how to solve this problem!

It should work from within an application, so I don't just need a webpage where you can enter the addresses and get a route back, I need something that has an API.

Comment: There are pretty good estimators that are fast. I assume a near optimal solution would be ok?

Comment: Yes of course. I suppose an optimal solution isn't even possible with more than like 20 waypoints, which I need...

Comment: @DominicM:If my answer is helpful consider to accept it!!!

Answer (score 5):

Gebweb tsp solver can help you to find a route. It's free. Link: https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/

> The solver source code is available under the MIT license. If you are interested in knowing  about updates to this code, please subscribe to this mailing list.

Comment: is it possible to somehow get the route information directly from an application. Like doing a http request with all the addresses and getting back the route. Otherwise I can't really use it although it is very nice.

Comment: Are you serious? Gebweb tsp solver is a free library.  Of course you can do it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your link I just found this: http://www.gebweb.net/optimap/ where I didn't find any hint if it was open source

Comment: I stated in the about tab of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Maps API for Business allows for 23 waypoints. See:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions

Find: Array of intermediate waypoints.

You're a Business Man, so this should work.